# why won't protractor recognize Angular ?

Tags: protractor

protractor is giving me errors telling me it can't find angular on the page. what else should I be considering to trouble shoot this ?

protractorConf.js

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome' },
  specs: ['spec/javascripts/integration/main_spec.js'],
  baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

Failure message, a browser is actually opening, which is an improvement on where i was yesterday, any thoughts on this ?

```
jd@mbp ~/Dropbox/apps/lookingtolunch (master *)]$ protractor protractorConf.js
Using the selenium server at http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub
F

Failures:

  1) E2E: main page should find title element
   Message:
     Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://127.0.0.1:3000/ : angular never provided resumeBootstrap
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://127.0.0.1:3000/ : angular never provided resumeBootstrap
    at assertAngularOnPage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:668:13)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.executeScript()
    at Protractor.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:675:15)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jd/Dropbox/apps/lookingtolunch/spec/javascripts/integration/main_spec.js:16:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/jasminewd/index.js:54:12
    at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
==== async task ====
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/jasminewd/index.js:53:12)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/async-callback.js:45:37)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Comment: Could you provide your html ?

Comment: Put your test in here also. I would assume that you aren't using `browser.get()` properly.

Comment: Check that your version of angular is up to date. I got this error when I was using Angular 1.0.4 js in my page. Upgrading to 1.2.9 fixed it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I am also getting the same problem, and since OP has gone silent, maybe I can use this answer space to give a second instance of the problem, and edit it to make it work based on other users feedback.

**edit**: *I've found a solution. See edit at the bottom of the answer*

I'm running Windows 8.1 running `webdriver-manager start` to launch Selenium standalone server, and `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` to host the site.

**example-specs.js**

```
describe("something peaceful", function() {
    it("shouldn't be this hard", function() {
        browser.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000"); // times out here
        expect(true).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

**conf.js**

```
// protractor configuration for end-to-end (e2e) tests
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome' },
    specs: [ 'example-specs.js' ],
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body ng-app >
    I can add: {{1+5}}.

    <!-- script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/**1.0.4**/angular.min.js"></script -->

    <!-- Updated to 1.2.9 and the problem went away -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**edit 1**
I was running from WebStorm, but I also tried serving the site using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (and changing the address accordingly), but my results are the same.

**edit 2**
If I remove `baseUrl` and call `browser.get(...)` directly, I can get `http://www.angularjs.org` work, but not my local site, nor this [jsfiddle angular app I found](http://fiddle.jshell.net/carpasse/mcVfK/3/show/#/home). Maybe it's just not working for **automatic bootstrapping**?

**edit 3**
Significantly reduced code to reproduce (removed controller). Moved script to the end of the body [as recommended](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

**edit 4**
I was using an old version (1.0.4) of Angular that [appeared in this book](http://bit.ly/14kRyQN). Upgrading to 1.2.9 (latest) fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks. For me it was because of missing `<body ng-app>`

Comment: So is this a new question or an answer? It’s not clear by reading.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to navigate to a page which does not use Angular then Add this line of code before `browser.get()` line there:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Reference : https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load

Comment: Please add to your answer the relevant contents from the link you referred, as t kake easier for others to identify the relevant part of the referenced link. Thanks